# Spring: @Service class with constructor with @Autowired(required = false) parameters: how to initialize it with these parameters?

Tags: java, spring

I have a service class that I want to dynamically initialize with different incoming values of constructor parameters:

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    private final SomeProperties someProperties;
    private final String url;
    private final String password;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceImpl(SomeProperties someProperties,
                             @Autowired(required = false) String url,
                             @Autowired(required = false) String password) {
        this.someProperties = someProperties;
        this.url = url;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Is it possible to initialize during runtime this `@Service` inside another spring component class by using own supplied `@Autowired(required = false)` parameters (in this case own url and password)? How would this code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
@Configuration
class SomeConfigClass {


    @Autowired
    SomeProperties someProperties

    @Value("${url1}")
    String url1

    @Value("${password1}")
    String password1

    ..............
     // Do this for other url's and properties or check out @ConfigurationProperties
    ..............

    @Bean("someService1")
    public SomeService() {
        return new SomeService(someProperties, url1, password1);
    }


    @Bean("someService2")
    public SomeService() {
        return new SomeService(someProperties, url2, password2);
    }

    ...............

    ..............
}
```

Create a factory class

```
@Configuration //typo corrected
class SomeServiceFactory {

  @Autowired // Spring will Autowire all instances of SomeService with bean name as key
  Map<String, SomeService> someServiceMap;

  public SomeService getSomeServiceByName(String name) {
    return someServiceMap.get(name);
  }
}
```

Then you can use the instance like this

```
@RestController
class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    SomeServiceFactory someServiceFactory;


    public void someEndpoint() {
     SomeService someService1 = SomeServiceFactory.getSomeServiceByName("someService1"); //You need to decide what argument to pass based on condition
     someService1.someFunction(...); // this will have url1 and password1
   } 
}
```

Comment: I want to initialize the class with given properties without any additional interaction via getters and setters.

Comment: but these properties aren't fixed right? I mean do you know these properties at compile time ?

Comment: these properties are fixed and they are stored in yaml file. I do not want to generate 4 service classes based on one abstract class which is implementing an interface. I want to initialize just one service class with different constructor values of properties inside one component. Something like this.

Comment: What do you mean you want to have changed at runtime? If your properties are fixed (as they're defined in the `application.properties` file) how are you planning on changing them on runtime? Also what do you mean by changing them on rutime?

Comment: Thanks! At the same time solved this also like you described :)

Comment: @pvpkiran btw how is this solution in terms of testability versus just using the abstract class and 4 children of it using different values of properties for each case?

Comment: from whatever i could understand from your question. I could say this.
1. Creating abstract class and 4 implementations: From design perspective, this is not a parent child relation, what you are changing is just two variables. Why would you want to introduce Inhertiance, where is absolutely no need. Delegation is always better than Inheritance
2. Coming to the solution I gave. This is also not an ideal solution, since we are creating 4 different classes. 
In my view, ideal solution in your case is the one i gave earlier, set different url and password using setters based on diff conditions

Comment: setting url and passwords using setters, gives you the flexibility. What I mean is, in solution 1 and 2 discussed above, url and passwords should be known at compile time. But with setter approach, it could be completely dynamic and even static also works. Having said that, by using setters, you are not levaraging spring's capability of injection. But in this specific case i feel that is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Where user and password come from ?
Maybe you can simply remove them from constructor and use @Value annotation to read values from properties file ?

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    private final SomeProperties someProperties;

    @Value("${service.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${service.password}")
    private String password;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceImpl(SomeProperties someProperties) {
        this.someProperties = someProperties;
    }
```

Comment: This will not work, because the values for this parameters vary from method to method.